# low Sound volume on flash but normal in soundcloud. #Chrome

Tags: sound, google-chrome, flash

I have an odd issue ^^ I have a low volume on the flash player (zb. Youtube) on chrome. 
But a completely normal one on some online radio like soundcloud.
The volume is setted to max. but is still fairly low, let's say 50% of max)
Does someone ever had this comportment? and if yes, is there any sound level in the flash player independant to the chrome "app" volume?
Oooor any workaround? :D
Ubuntu 15.04 + Chrome 
Hope I can get some help there :)
Regards,

Comment: For what it's worth, I have this exact same problem on Windows 7 with Flash under Chrome.  The VU meters in the Windows mixer sit exactly at 50% for maxed out sound under Flash, but HTML5 audio is fine.  Did you find a solution?  I suspect this issue is everywhere.